# Fixed length reader doesn't return any sets in smooks?

Tags: java, smooks

I have a smooks configuration defined as:

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd">
    <fl:reader fields="RecordId[10],CompactedCorpName[60],FileNumber[9]" skipLines="1"></fl:reader>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

When I try to get XML output from this; (I pass a text file which contains series of fixed length characters)
I'm getting empty 'set'.

```
<set></set>
```

Can anyone help me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, my file contains some line, which is less than the actual character length. So, smooks can not process it.